Getting UNAVAILABLE: io exception Channel Pipeline while trying to add data into bigtable
I recently started working on BigTable to ingest/ read the data to it
Since it is a POC I am using free GCP account.
I have enabled cloud bigtable api and to my service account have added all the required roles like big data viewer/reader/administrater et cetra.
But still when I tried to ingest the data using data client. Below is the ingestion code I am using to ingest to big table
I am using spring boot with java 17 app to ingest the data to big table and given GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS as an environment variable with the service account(added all the big table roles to it) json as value in intelliJ IDE tool
            long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000;
            String rowkey = "r1";
            RowMutation rowMutation = RowMutation.create(TABLE_NAME, rowkey);
            rowMutation.setCell(
                    COLUMN_FAMILY_NAME,
                    ByteString.copyFrom("connected_cell".getBytes()),
                    timestamp,
                    1L);
            bigtableDataClient.mutateRow(rowMutation);
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Successfully wrote row with key "+rowkey);

I am getting the below error with the  exception trace .
: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
Channel Pipeline: [SslHandler#0, ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler#0, WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]

com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnavailableException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
Channel Pipeline: [SslHandler#0, ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler#0, WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:112) ~[gax-2.35.0.jar:2.35.0]
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:41) ~[gax-2.35.0.jar:2.35.0]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:86) ~[gax-grpc-2.35.0.jar:2.35.0]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:66) ~[gax-grpc-2.35.0.jar:2.35.0]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97) ~[gax-grpc-2.35.0.jar:2.35.0]
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:84) ~[api-common-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1127) ~[guava-32.1.2-jre.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:31) ~[guava-32.1.2-jre.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1286) ~[guava-32.1.2-jre.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.addListener(AbstractFuture.java:760) ~[guava-32.1.2-jre.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingListenableFuture.addListener(ForwardingListenableFuture.java:45) ~[guava-32.1.2-jre.jar:na]
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutureToListenableFuture.addListener(ApiFutureToListenableFuture.java:49) ~[api-common-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.addCallback(Futures.java:1100) ~[guava-32.1.2-jre.jar:na]
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures.addCallback(ApiFutures.java:79) ~[api-common-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable.futureCall(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:67) ~[gax-grpc-2.35.0.jar:2.35.0]
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.stub.metrics.StatsHeadersUnaryCallable.futureCall(StatsHeadersUnaryCallable.java:41) ~[google-cloud-bigtable-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.stub.metrics.BigtableTracerUnaryCallable.futureCall(BigtableTracerUnaryCallable.java:62) ~[google-cloud-bigtable-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.AttemptCallable.call(AttemptCallable.java:87) ~[gax-2.35.0.jar:2.35.0]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:131) ~[guava-32.1.2-jre.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:75) ~[guava-32.1.2-jre.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:82) ~[guava-32.1.2-jre.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: com.google.api.gax.rpc.AsyncTaskException: Asynchronous task failed
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptions.callAndTranslateApiException(ApiExceptions.java:57) ~[gax-2.35.0.jar:2.35.0]
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.BigtableDataClient.mutateRow(BigtableDataClient.java:964) ~[google-cloud-bigtable-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at com.re.bigtable.controller.impl.ProfileControllerImpl.insert(ProfileControllerImpl.java:61) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:6.0]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:6.0]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
Channel Pipeline: [SslHandler#0, ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler#0, WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:537) ~[grpc-api-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:538) ~[grpc-stub-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39) ~[grpc-api-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23) ~[grpc-api-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40) ~[grpc-api-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool$ReleasingClientCall$1.onClose(ChannelPool.java:546) ~[gax-grpc-2.35.0.jar:2.35.0]
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39) ~[grpc-api-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23) ~[grpc-api-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40) ~[grpc-api-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcMetadataHandlerInterceptor$1$1.onClose(GrpcMetadataHandlerInterceptor.java:76) ~[gax-grpc-2.35.0.jar:2.35.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:567) ~[grpc-core-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:71) ~[grpc-core-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:735) ~[grpc-core-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:716) ~[grpc-core-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) ~[grpc-core-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133) ~[grpc-core-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General OpenSslEngine problem
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.handshakeException(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1929) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.wrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:836) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrap(SslHandler.java:1042) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrapNonAppData(SslHandler.java:928) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1419) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrapNonAppData(SslHandler.java:1337) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.access$1800(SslHandler.java:170) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslTasksRunner.resumeOnEventExecutor(SslHandler.java:1728) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslTasksRunner.access$2000(SslHandler.java:1619) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslTasksRunner$2.run(SslHandler.java:1780) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:285) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:144) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext$ExtendedTrustManagerVerifyCallback.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext.java:234) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext$AbstractCertificateVerifier.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.java:785) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.internal.tcnative.CertificateVerifierTask.runTask(CertificateVerifierTask.java:36) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSLTask.run(SSLTask.java:48) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSLTask.run(SSLTask.java:42) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.runAndResetNeedTask(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1518) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.access$700(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:94) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine$TaskDecorator.run(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1493) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslTasksRunner.run(SslHandler.java:1797) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434) ~[na:na]
    ... 16 common frames omitted

Got stuck on this issue for a while tried to play with the GCP account  by adding required API's /roles but not yeilding any results. Any of your help is highly appreciated.
At first was in an assumption that it is because of cert issue while connecting to gcp cloud and imported gcp cert to my dev machine and added it to cacerts of my jdk.
Then tried to play with the GCP account by adding required API's /roles.
Still it didn't solved the issue.
Any of your help is highly appreciated.
